# Custom text (code) areas in QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, custom-controls, qtextedit, qtextdocument

I am interested in creating a text object type (inheriting [QTextObjectInterface](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextobjectinterface.html)) that behaves like a code area:

- distinctive background
- border
- fixed-width font
- editable content
- the instances need to be identifiable to code, so that content inside them may be extracted (separate code from surrounding content)
- saving / loading (from regular html files)
- syntax highlighting would be a plus, but is not really required

The other areas of the document would need to behave the usual way (font properties editable, colors editable, etc).

---

Qt provides [an example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsvg-richtext-textobject-example.html) for implementing custom text objects with [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html). This looks like the hard way, since new text object can't make use of the existing infrastructure inside QTextEdit / [QTextDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html).

[QTextObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextobject.html) is

> a base class for different kinds of objects that can group parts of a [QTextDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html) together

so inheriting it may be a choice, but neither its source files in Qt SDK package nor Google searches revealed helpful information.

[QTextFrame](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextframe.html) inherits [QTextObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextobject.html) so, again, it may be a feasible base class if some hints about this path are to be found.

---

In an simple HTML file all this (except syntax highlighting) would be easy. [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) takes html as input and is able to export html, but the structure is lost in the process.

```
<code class="code-sample">
  int i = 0;
</code>
```

[QWebView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebview.html) is read-only, by the way. It advertises that:

> Parts of HTML documents can be editable for example through the contenteditable attribute on HTML elements.

---

There may be other platforms where this is readily available, but the text editor needs to be used inside Qt Creator as a plug-in, so using Qt framework makes sense.

Bottom line: how does one implement code areas in a [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) widget?

---

Later edits:

- using Qt sdk from trunk (identifies itself as 4.8.4)
- Qt Creator from trunk (Qt Creator 2.6.81)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found out that implementing this is possible using QTextEdit / QTextDocument.The most simple implementation that I can think of is presented in this answer for the reference of future seeker.

Notice that saving/loading needs to be customised as regular .toHtml() will not preserve the information needed.

Inserting a code block is simple:

```
QTextFrame * frame;

frame = cursor.insertFrame( code_block_format_ );
connect( frame, SIGNAL( destroyed() ),
  this, SLOT( codeBlockDeleted() ) );
code_blocks_.append( frame );
```

notice the two variables that you can save in the class:

```
QTextFrameFormat code_block_format_;
QList<const QTextFrame*> code_blocks_;
```

We need the format for frame to be consistent and distinctive. It mat be initialised in constructor to something like:

```
code_block_format_.setBackground( QBrush( Qt::yellow ) );
code_block_format_.setBorder( 1 );
code_block_format_.setBorderStyle( QTextFrameFormat::BorderStyle_Inset);
code_block_format_.setMargin( 10 );
code_block_format_.setPadding( 4 );
```

We need the list so we can tell if a certain frame is a code box or not. Since all objects inheriting QTextObject need to be created by QTextDocument::createObject() we can't simply subclass the QTextFrame (actually I think we can, but not sure yet).

Now separating the code content from the rest may be done the usual way:

```
for ( it = frame->begin(); !(it.atEnd()); ++it ) {
  child_frame = it.currentFrame();
  child_block = it.currentBlock();
  if ( child_frame != NULL )
  {
    if ( code_blocks_.contains( frame ) )
    {
      /* ... */
    }
  }
} /* for ( it = frame->begin(); !(it.atEnd()); ++it ) */
```

but notice that this is over-simplified for the sake of brevity. One needs to take into account nested frames.

If you are interested in a full implementation check out the [git repository](https://gitorious.org/proliterate) (work in progress, November 2012).